# WPF: external font in WPF application from Resources folder

Tags: wpf, fonts

So i have this `Label` style:

```
<Style x:Key="LabelLightStyle" TargetType="Label">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="10.5"/>>
</Style>
```

And i want to use specific `Font` that not installed on my machine so i put this `.ttf` file in my application `Resources` folder and add this to my `Label` style:

```
<Setter Property="TextElement.FontFamily" Value="Resources/#ABSTRACT" />
```

But it seems that nothing happens and the font doesn't change.

But when override this font and put this inside my controller:

```
<Label
    Name="lblTest"
    Content="File"
    FontFamily="Resources/#Polentical Neon"
    Margin="0,0,0,0" />
```

This works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use a pack URI:

```
<Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="pack://application:,,,/Resources/#ABSTRACT" />
```

Also make sure that the `Build Action` of the `.ttf` file has been set to `Resource` and that `ABSTRACT` is the actual *name* of the font family and not just the name of the file.